# Re-importing products to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Magento Store A has 100% of all products listed. Magento Store B imported about 90% of those products and then, while still under development, stopped importing new products that were added to Store A.

Store A is Magento 1.6, Store B is Magento 1.9.1.

My question is: if I re-run the import/export process from Store A to Store B, will the pre-existing products in Store B be overwritten, or will the process result in duplicate listings in Store B?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you importing products into Store B (what method/tool)?  Are you simply migrating the products from Store A to Store B?

Comment: I am using the System > Import/Export > Dataflow profiles > Import All Products wizard

Comment: To answer your question, you cannot have 2 products with the same SKU in Magento, so if you reimport the items with the same skus they will be overwritten.